# How to calculate a coefficient depending on a frame rate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm developing a game and currently it updates the game world 60 times per second, and I have the following code which works perfectly when the game is updating at that rate:

```
forceX *= 0.98;
forceY *= 0.98;
```

However, I would like to change the tick rate to 20 now, but still achieve the same effect. So, I realized that if the game updates 60 updates per second, then that's 3 updates in 50 milliseconds. So if the starting number was 10, then after 50 milliseconds, the result would look like:

```
10 * 0.98 * 0.98 * 0.98 = 9.41192
```

Because an update at a 60 tick rate happens every `16.667` milliseconds, so after `16.667 * 3 = 50` milliseconds, the initial value would be `9.41192`

Similarly, if the tick rate was 20, then a single update would occur once every 50 milliseconds.

So I would need to do:

```
10 * x = 9.41192
```

To get the same result for what the value will be after 50 milliseconds. And in this case `x` is `0.941192`

Which means at a 60 tick rate, the x value is `0.98`, and at a 20 tick rate, our x value is `0.941192`

My question is, how do we calculate this? That is, can we devise a function, that, given the following inputs, returns the following outputs?

```
fn(60) = 0.98
fn(20) = 0.941192
```

If so, how? Sorry if this question is very basic. Math is not my strong suit.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! Hmm, I tried that and when I substituted `20` in for `x` I got the value `0.993288`, which isn't correct. I'm looking for a function that will output `0.98` when the input is `60` and output `0.941192` when the input is `20`. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself properly.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misspoke, I meant $0.98^{\frac{60}{x}}$. The function you're looking for is much more specific than what you just said; for example, if the tick rate changes to $10$ you want to apply the update $6$ times, and in general if the tick rate changes to $x$ you want to apply the update $\frac{60}{x}$ times. That's what this does.

Comment: Ahh perfect, thanks so much! This looks great